# print invoice data blank php foreach loop error

Tags: php

I want to print invoice data. but some error only one image print. how to print all data in an invoice I am using PHP 7.2 and loop foreach please help me...

```
error->Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xammp\htdocs\tam\admin\invoice.php on line 133
```

**PHP GET id wise invoice data script**

```
 <?php 
require 'setting/config.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query="select * from orders where id='$id'";
$galrun=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($galrun);
$total=$result['total']; 

 $array[0]=$result['image'];
 $array[1]=$result['productName'];
 $array[2]=$result['product_qty'];
 $array[3]=$result['salseprice'];

$resultdata= implode(",", $array);

 ?>
```

**HTML invoice**

```
 <table class="table">
              <thead>
                   <tr>
                     <th>Sr. No.</th>
                    <th>image</th>
                     <th>Description</th>
                     <th>Qty</th>
                     <th>Amount</th>
                      <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
        <?php

                      foreach ($resultdata as $item){
                        ?>
                      <tr>
                       <td> ? </td>
                       <td><img src="image/product/<?php echo $item[0] ; ?>" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
                       <td><?php echo $item[1] ; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $item[2] ; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $item[3] ; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $total ; ?</td>

                     </tr>
                      <?php }?>                               
           </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xammp\htdocs\tam\admin\invoice.php on line 132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to loop through `$resultdata`, but it is a string, because of this part:

```
$resultdata= implode(",", $array);
```

PHP `implode()` returns a string.